gz-tools2 stopping ros2 gazebo control package being installed on ros2 humble
I've been trying to install the ros2 control packages needed for gazebo, one of which is:
sudo apt install ros-humble-gazebo-ros2-control

When I run this command I get the following error:
sudo apt install ros-humble-gazebo-ros2-control
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 gz-tools2 : Conflicts: gazebo (>= 11.0.0) but 11.10.2+dfsg-1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.


I've found someone (https://github.com/gazebosim/gazebo-classic/issues/3277) suggesting I delete the file that is causing the issue, but isn't gz-tools2 necassary for gazebo to function?
I'm unsure of what to do and would greatly appreciate any help.

No it is not needed nor installed automatically with gazebo11, at least on Ubuntu 22.04 (see apt show libgazebo-dev). Which debian are you using?
I think that the issue you linked is a good hint how to solve this.

Sorry for the late reply. I'm using humble as my ros2 debian. I'm not sure where to locate the gz-tools2 package so I can remove it like in the link I showed in the original post.

Nevermind, I found was able to remove the package using sudo apt --purge remove gs-tools2. Now the package downloads fine! I think gz-tools2 is from gazebo classic, but I don't know how I have it because I only installed ignition-fortress on my system, weird. Thank you for the help!
